# How do i ensure no duplicates with this query

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT keyword FROM url_aliAS WHERE query = CONCAT("category_id" , '=', p2c.category_id)) AS something,
    p.product_id, p.model FROM product AS p 
    JOIN product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)  
        WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (280, 129, 131)
```

and the rows being returned have duplicate `product_id`. For example:-

```
something       product_id  model
NULL            20         18924
barcode_labels  20         18924
NULL            21         18926
barcode_labels  21         18926
NULL            22         30332
barcode_labels  22         30332
```

I tried `DISTINCT` on the `product_id` and I also tried in the `WHERE` clause "and something is not null" and both failed. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you really start with two `select`s? Also I don't understand your output for `something`... shouldn't it have some category id's, some equals signs, and so on?

Comment: can you try and list the table structures involved? I would love to get rid of that nested query.

Comment: sure one sec...let me update my question

Comment: @Chris: the OP's query is valid MySQL syntax. And the output of `something` is whatever is stored in the `keyword` field; not what is in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Have you tried GROUP BY product_id?

Comment: @Adam Bernier Oops --- I missed the parentheses; now that the formatting has been cleaned up it's a lot easier to follow.

Comment: @Adam, nevertheless, nested queries are evil, and in 99.9% can be replaced with JOINs and prober database layout.

Comment: The tables are a bit big but one this is for sure there is no relationship to th eurl_alias table which has the field query which will have the string category_id=40 in it so i cant join on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want something like this (I also refactored the code a bit). However, if you have more than just `barcode_labels` as a keyword, you'll still get an additional entry for each other combination.

```
select
    u.keyword as something,
    product_id,
    p.model
from
    product p
    join product_to_category p2c using (product_id)
    join url_alias u on (u.query = concat("category_id=", p2c.category_id))
where
    u.keyword is not null
    and p.product_id not in (280, 129, 131)
```

Another way would be to play around with the `group by` clause to get what you want. Try something like this:

```
select
    max(u.keyword) as something,
    product_id,
    p.model
from
    product p
    join product_to_category p2c using (product_id)
    join url_alias u on (u.query = concat("category_id=", p2c.category_id))
where
    u.keyword is not null
    and p.product_id not in (280, 129, 131)
group by
    product_id,
    p.model
```

Comment: this looks very promising but its returning nothing

Comment: I added some extra spaces on accident, looks like it should have been "category_id=". I edited the code just now, see if that fixes it

Comment: weird...its not fixing it but i love the structure of the query...just not sure why its not working

Comment: try changing the from clause to `product p join product_to_category p2c using (product_id) join url_alias u on (u.query = ("category_id=" || p2c.category_id))` and take out the u.query where statement. If that doesn't work try changing the concat back to the `CONCAT` statement you had before. Maybe || only works in postgres?

Comment: Just confirmed that. In MySQL, `||` is the same as a logical OR. In PostgreSQL, `||` is the concatenation operator. I'll edit the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the records:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT keyword FROM url_aliAS WHERE query = CONCAT("category_id" , '=', p2c.category_id)) AS something,
p.product_id, p.model FROM product AS p 
JOIN product_to_category p2c ON (p.product_id = p2c.product_id)  
    WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (280, 129, 131)
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

but you don't have alot of control over which information is displayed after the grouping. In your case, in the something column, should it show `NULL` or `barcode_labels`?